# What's the largest screen for watching videos on the ISS?

Tags: iss, astronaut-lifestyle, computer

There are many laptops on the ISS, for [controlling non-critical things](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/19252/12102) and for personal use during free time. Even at least one iPad.

Are these the largest screens available? If the crew wants to watch something together or there's a live event, do they have anything bigger than a laptop to watch?

Screen shot (annotated) from [One of the Most Detailed ISS Tours!](https://youtu.be/QvTmdIhYnes) (NASA astronaut Steven Swanson):

[image]

Comment: Depends on the movie. The ISS live stream can be watched on a 3m diagonal, in 3D, panoramic ultra-HDR and QHD++

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's at least one **projector** that gets used for movies. From the ISS National Laboratory blog post [Movie Night on the International Space Station](https://www.iss-casis.org/blog/movie-night-on-the-international-space-station/):

> NASA astronaut, Joe Acaba, posted this image showing the crew relaxing together while watching a movie. According to him “I can’t think of a better movie theater to watch Star Wars than on the Space Station!”

[image]

Apparently there's a fairly well-stocked movie library aboard. A FOIA request revealed its extent, shown in Gizmodo's [The Complete List of Movies and TV Shows On Board the International Space Station](https://paleofuture.gizmodo.com/the-complete-list-of-movies-and-tv-shows-on-the-interna-1782918945)

As for largest screen size, perhaps *the sky's the limit?*

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I've made some edits, I hope you don't mind. I originally thought that was *Top Gun* for some reason, but it turns out that it's *Star Wars*. I get them mixed up, it was a confusing decade.

Comment: Apparently some engineering went into the projector screen itself too https://www.screeninnovations.com/screen/iss-viewscreen/

Comment: ...as well as into the video about the engineering that went into the screen! However in your image they are still using clips to try to hold it flat and that doesn't seem to be working so well ;-)